# What is fermion anomaly?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

In the proposal of single electron source (PRL 97,116403 (2006)), the author mentioned that "a large momentum transfer $2n\hbar k_F$ associated with an excitation which is slow on the scale of Fermi energy can be understood as a fermion anomaly". My question is, what the "fermion anomaly" means?

Comment: My guess is that this is related to chiral anomaly, where by applying a small electric field to 1D electron gas, electrons flow from the left fermi point to the right with a momentum transfer of $2k_F$.